# Android Sqlite when data are not exist

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm new in Android and SQL and I have the following problem where I don't know how to solve.

I have the below table

```
users 
id, name
1, user 1

articles 

id, article_text 
1, test article 


comments
article_id, users_id, article_comment
1         ,    1    , test comment 1
2         ,    2    , test comment 2
```

I get all the comments like this

```
select users.*, comments.* from Comments, users where users_id = user._id
```

The problem with the query above is that I don't get the second comment "test comment 2" because I don't have the user in the user table, can you help please?

Please note that I can't insert the second user in the users table.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select users.*, comments.* from users LEFT OUTER JOIN Comments where Comments.users_id = user._id
```